# highcharts pie using javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm using the pie chart and just have a question. I'm filling a couple of arrays with json data like this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) { 
    r = json.results[i];
    a_dataPerct.push(r.Percentage);
    a_dataOptionName.push(r.OptionName);
}
```

In the series: data: property of the chart (I'm assuming this is where it would go??) when I just do this...

```
data: a_dataPerct
```

the percentages show up fine on the chart and the chart displays, but it says "Slice" for each section.

I want the a_dataOptionName values to be the names there instead of "Slice". How do I do that? I thought it might be like this...

```
data: a_dataOptionName,a_dataPerct
```

but it didn't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pie charts data is a twodimentional array with [name, number], like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) { 
    r = json.results[i];
    a_dataPerct.push([r.OptionName, r.Percentage]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: '',
                    data:

```
            }],
        x:[{        

                data:<?php echo $jastudentcount; ?> 
                }]
```

formatter: function() {
                            return '**'+ this.point.name +'**: '+'('+ this.y +')'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2)+' %';
                        }